# fibonacci sequence only works within a while loop, and not "for" loop

Tags: c++

```
std::cout << "How many fibonacci numbers do you wish to calculate" << std::endl;
int amount = 0;
std::cin >> amount;

int num1 = 0;
int num2 = 1;


while(true){
for(int i = 0; i < amount; ++i){
    std::cout << num1 + num2 << std::endl;

    int Num2Temp = num2;
    num2 = num1 + num2;
    num1 = Num2Temp;
}
}
```

The above code works exactly the way I want it. However, when I take away the while loop and leave in the for loop to loop by itself; the code stops working. The numbers printed just go up by 1 , and doesn't produce the fibonacci sequence that I wanted. 
I know there's an infinite loop with the true. However, I just wanted to know why the for loop only doesn't work. Which is the one I originally wrote.

Here is the code that does not work:

```
    std::cout << "How many fibonacci numbes do you wish to calculate" << std::endl;
int amount = 0;
std::cin >> amount;

int num1 = 0;
int num2 = 1;

for(int i = 0; i < amount; ++i){
    std::cout << num1 + num2 << std::endl;

    int Num2Temp = num2;
    num2 = num1 + num2;
    num1 = Num2Temp;
}
```

Output:
How many fibonacci numbes do you wish to calculate
3 //I want to calculate up to 3, is user input

1
2
3

Comment: *The above code works exactly the way I want it.* That proves that you are a *patient* person. Most people are not willing to wait infinitely for a program to stop...

Comment: can you perhaps post a version of the code that didn't work, and some sample output?

Comment: I'm your complete opposite, then. I get the correct output when I remove the while loop.

Comment: "Stops working" means what, exactly? Sample output is desired.

Comment: There's no reason why the `while` loop should change anything with regards to the output.  What it _will_ do is cause the `for` loop to be executed indefinitely...and by indefinitely I mean from 0 to amount over and over and over again, not from 0 to infinity.

Comment: i added the code that doesn't work for me

Comment: @user2608474 The output you added as "doesn't work" is the correct output (except it starts at 1 instead of 0), what's the problem?

Comment: What do you think the first 3 Fibonacci numbers are?

Comment: It works: -http://ideone.com/RWocXx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your output is to be expected for only 3 iterations.

the first Fibonacci numbers are (1), **1**, **2**, and **3**

try running for more than 5 iterations, the one after `3` should be `5` and then `8` after that

Comment: Wow that is amazing. I'm almost certain I had the exact same code and it didn't work. I tried it with 100, 3, 10; nothing. I kept trying to figure out whats wrong. Now, all of the sudden it works! I'm not sure what is going on here.....